# testing.logF logging doesn't work when debugging tests in vs code go

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, delve

We have some `go` tests written in our repo that I am trying to debug. We mostly use [logF](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Logf) from `testing.T` package for logging purposes. I am trying to debug tests using "Debug Test" button in VS code and expect to see logs in Debug Console window. (check screenshot below)

["Debug Test" button in Vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cj4z.png)

When I click on "Debug Tests", this is the command that runs in Debug Console

`{work_dir}/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:36859 --log-dest=3 from {test_path}`

I don't see logs using `logF` method showing up in Debug Console. However logs from [fmt.Println](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) shows up in Debug Console.

I have tried multiple dlv log options (from `dlv log help`) but don't see anything working for me. Does `logF` logging work in dlv debugging?

Comment: `fmt` prints to stdout, `logF` likely logs to stderr.

Comment: Thanks for checking @icza. logF does record the text in the error log, that's what the documentation says. Is there a way to redirect stderr logs to Debug Console?

Comment: You could set the output of the logger to `os.Stdout`.

Comment: I tried checking documentation for "testing"  package and unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any option for redirecting logs to stdout https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T

Comment: If test passes, by default, `go test` command does not print t.Logf. If you want to see the logging even when test succeeds, `"go.testFlags": ["-v"]`

From the testing package documentation: "For tests, the text will be printed only if the test fails or the -test.v flag is set. For benchmarks, the text is always printed to avoid having performance depend on the value of the -test.v flag."

DEBUG CONSOLE outputs stdout and stderr if the program ever outputs.

Comment: Thanks for replying Hana. When I click "Run tests", I was always able to see the logs, as per documentation I had to add `-v` arg. I am interested in "Debug test" where I don't see logs from LogF method. Thank you.